# Javascript redirect causing IE 'null' is null or not an object error

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

I'm trying to A/B test our product drop view.  below is the javascript code I'm using:

```
  var url = window.location.href,
      defaultType = 'Gallery',
      otherType = 'List';
  if(Cookie.read('SEARCHVIEW') == otherType && Cookie.read('viewTypeChanged') != otherType){
      if(url.contains('v='+otherType)){
        url = url.replace('v='+otherType, 'v='+defaultType);
      }else if(url.contains('?')){
        url = url + '&v='+defaultType;
      }else{
        url = url + '?v='+defaultType;
      }

      window.location = url;
    }
```

After the page redirects in IE I get the dreaded `'null' is null or not an object` and `Object does not support this property or method` errors.

This is happening in both IE 7 & 8

How can I fix this?

Comment: If the error occurs *after* the redirect, what makes you think this code is responsible? Isn't it more likely that the problem lies with some code that is on the page you redirected to?

Comment: Getting to grips with a javascript debugger would be infinitely more helpful to you in the long run than asking here. IE8 has developer tools (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd565622%28VS.85%29.aspx), IE7 you can use "Script Debugger for Windows NT 4.0 and Later" (http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=2f465be0-94fd-4569-b3c4-dffdf19ccd99&displaylang=en)

Comment: @Robusto The errors don't show up if I don't do the redirect.  If I just go to page I'm redirecting to, there are no JS errors

Comment: the point is that if the redirect **happens at all** then that means that this code is dead and gone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve the problem. and for future reference I'll post some code and explain.
The offending code looks like this:

```
&lt;script type="text/javascript"&gt;

 window.addEvent('domready', function(){


  $('v_toggle').addEvents({
   'mouseenter': function(e){
   $('vertical_slide_container').show();

  },
   'mouseleave': function(e){
   $('vertical_slide_container').hide();

  }
  });
 });
 &lt;/script&gt;

&lt;/head&gt;

&lt;body&gt;


&lt;div class="mboxDefault"&gt;/div&gt;
&lt;script type="text/javascript"&gt;mboxCreate('header',etc...);&lt;/script&gt;
```

My company uses Omniture for our A/B testing and my code was being run in the `mboxCreate()` function.  You'll notice above that there is code adding a `domready` event which adds hover events to our navigtaion(which is incidentally below my `mboxCreate()` code).  What was happening was my code was redirecting, which stopped the page from loading, which also signaled that the DOM was ready.  So when I called the redirect, the DOM ready code was run and was trying to add hover events on DOM elements that did not exists.

Thus the `'null' is null or not an object'` and the `object does not support this method or property` errors.

The solution to the problem was to remove all `domready` events before I redirected so my error free code looks like this:

```
  var url = window.location.href,
      defaultType = 'Gallery',
      otherType = 'List';
  if(Cookie.read('SEARCHVIEW') == otherType && Cookie.read('viewTypeChanged') != otherType){
      if(url.contains('v='+otherType)){
        url = url.replace('v='+otherType, 'v='+defaultType);
      }else if(url.contains('?')){
        url = url + '&v='+defaultType;
      }else{
        url = url + '?v='+defaultType;
      }
      window.removeEvents('domready');
      window.location = url;
    }
```

Answer (score -2):

href is not a property of window it can be used with anchor() object, try to use only window.location and this should work.

Comment: window.location.href is absolutely part of the window object. see http://davidwalsh.name/javascript-window-location. window.location.href returns the full URL string